# expected string or buffer when processing text file with python

Tags: python, text-processing

I'm processing a large (120mb) text file from my thunderbird imap directory and attempting to extract to/from info from the headers using mbox and regex. the process runs for a while until I eventually get an exception: "TypeError: expected string or buffer".

The exception references the fifth line of this code:

```
PAT_EMAIL = re.compile(r"[0-9A-Za-z._-]+\@[0-9A-Za-z._-]+")
temp_list = []
mymbox = mbox("data.txt")
for email in mymbox.values():
    from_address = PAT_EMAIL.findall(email["from"]) 
    to_address = PAT_EMAIL.findall(email["to"])
    for item in from_address:
        temp_list.append(item) #items are added to a temporary list where they are sorted then written to file
```

I've run the code on other (smaller) files, so I'm guessing the issue is my file. The file appears to be just a bunch of text. Can someone point me in the write direction for debugging this?

Comment: Check `type(email["from"])` in the iterations where it fails.

Comment: Can you post the code for your `findall` method?

Comment: added findall method to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't solve the issue but have worked around it for my own purposes. I inserted a try statement so that the iteration just continues past any TypeError. For every thousand email addresses I'm getting about 8 failures, which will suffice. Thanks for your input!

```
PAT_EMAIL = re.compile(r"[0-9A-Za-z._-]+\@[0-9A-Za-z._-]+")
temp_list = []
mymbox = mbox("data.txt")
for email in mymbox.values():
    try:
        from_address = PAT_EMAIL.findall(email["from"])
    except(TypeError):
        print "TypeError!"
    try:
        to_address = PAT_EMAIL.findall(email["to"])
    except(TypeError):
        print "TypeError!"
    for item in from_address:
        temp_list.append(item) #items are added to a temporary list where they are sorted then written to file
```

Comment: being able to skip the failures in this way is OK if this meets your needs. You can of course (although I am risking stating the very obvious here) use the except-section to print out 'email' and find out what is causing the failure so that you can perhaps avoid the errors altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `from` address (I think!):

In the following:

```
from_address = PAT_EMAIL.findall(email["from"])
```

I have a feeling you're trying to duplicate the work of [email.message_from_file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file) and [email.utils.parseaddr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr)

```
from email.utils import parseaddr

>>> s = "Jon Clements <jon@example.com>"
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> parseaddr(s)
('Jon Clements', 'jon@example.com')
```

So you can use `parseaddr(email['from'])[1]` to get the email address and use that.

Similarly, you may wish to look at [email.utils.getaddresses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses) to handle `to` and `cc` addresses...